# The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed error in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'am trying to upload some document in php code-igniter, allowed types are

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|pptx|ppt|docx|xls|xlsx|doc';
$config['max_size'] = '2000000';
```

only pptx format is not supporting.
size is less than 2MB
I'am using CI version 2.0.1

Comment: Please expand the question so we can see what you are trying to achieve

Comment: try to debug upload error like this:
if ( !$this->upload->do_upload()){
 echo $this->upload->display_errors();
}

Comment: when i displaying the error ,showing that "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed."

Comment: Upgrade version of your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug of Codeigniter.

You need to edit this file:

```
application/config/mime.php
```

and replace line no 33 (probably) with the following line:

```
'ppt'   =>  array('application/powerpoint', 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint', 'application/vnd.ms-office', 'application/msword'),
```

and add the following line to the array:

```
'pptx'  =>  array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation', 'application/zip', 'application/msword','application/vnd.ms-powerpoint'),
```